# R validate package. Create indicator object for arbitrary column

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm coming up against a problem that makes me very puzzled about how the language works.  There is a package, "validate", that can create objects you can use to check that your data is as expected. 
Testing it out on some toy data, I found that while the following code worked as expected:

```
library(validate)

I <- indicator( 
   cnt_misng =  number_missing(x)    
 , sum = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
 , min = min(x, na.rm = TRUE)
 , mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
 , max = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
) 

dat <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=c(NA,11,7,8), z=c(NA,2,0,NA))
C <- confront(dat, I)
values(C)
```

However, I found that I could not create a function that would return an indicator object for any arbitrary column of the data frame.  This was my failed attempt:

```
check_values <- function(data, x){ 
    print(x)
    I <- indicator( 
        cnt_misng =  number_missing(eval(x))    
        , max = max(eval(x), na.rm = TRUE)
    ) 
    C <- confront(df, I)
    return(C)
}

df <- data.frame(A=1:4, B=c(NA,11,7,8), C=c(NA,2,0,NA))
C <- check_values(df,'B')
values(C)
```

If I have a large dataset, I'd like to be able to loop through a list of columns and have an identically formatted report for each one in the list.  At this point, I'll probably give up on this package and find another way to more directly do that.  However, I am still curious how this could be made to work.  It seems like there should be a way to functionalize the creation of this indicator object so I can reuse the code to check the same stats for any arbitrary column of a data frame.

Any ideas?